# Angular - Select option does not list my array

Tags: angular, drop-down-menu

I have been trying to create a list of cities in Turkey, I get cities from api, checked the array and array works correctly. But, I can not show cities on options of select. It comes as blank, with a disabled option.

```
<div class="col-md-3">
  <select name="city" id="city" formControlName="city">
    <option [ngValue]="null" disabled>Select City</option>
    <option *ngFor="let city of cities" [ngValue]="city.id">{{city.name}}</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Here is my code where I get cities:

```
cities: City[] = []
constructor(private locationService: LocationService){
    locationService.getCities()
    .subscribe(res => {
      this.cities = res
    })
}
```

It works fine with another project, but not on this one. I copied & pasted it. Here is my dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~13.0.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "~13.3.4",
    "@angular/common": "~13.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~13.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "~13.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~13.0.0",
    "@angular/material": "~13.3.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~13.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~13.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "~13.0.0",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.5.14",
    "angular-notifier": "^11.0.0",
    "jquery": "^3.6.0",
    "ng-recaptcha": "^9.0.0",
    "ngx-cookie-service": "^13.2.0",
    "rxjs": "~7.4.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~13.0.4",
    "@angular/cli": "~13.0.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~13.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.10.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.10.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~1.7.0",
    "typescript": "~4.4.3"
  }
```

Here is what I get when I log the cities in subscription:

```
booking.component.ts:89 Array(81)0: {id: 1, name: 'ADANA'}1: {id: 2, name: 'ADIYAMAN'}2: {id: 3, name: 'AFYON'}3: {id: 4, name: 'AĞRI'}4: {id: 5, name: 'AMASYA'}5: {id: 6, name: 'ANKARA'}6: {id: 7, name: 'ANTALYA'}7: {id: 8, name: 'ARTVİN'}8: {id: 9, name: 'AYDIN'}9: {id: 10, name: 'BALIKESİR'}10: {id: 11, name: 'BİLECİK'}11: {id: 12, name: 'BİNGÖL'}12: {id: 13, name: 'BİTLİS'}13: {id: 14, name: 'BOLU'}14: {id: 15, name: 'BURDUR'}15: {id: 16, name: 'BURSA'}16: {id: 17, name: 'ÇANAKKALE'}17: {id: 18, name: 'ÇANKIRI'}18: {id: 19, name: 'ÇORUM'}19: {id: 20, name: 'DENİZLİ'}20: {id: 21, name: 'DİYARBAKIR'}21: {id: 22, name: 'EDİRNE'}22: {id: 23, name: 'ELAZIĞ'}23: {id: 24, name: 'ERZİNCAN'}24: {id: 25, name: 'ERZURUM'}25: {id: 26, name: 'ESKİŞEHİR'}26: {id: 27, name: 'GAZİANTEP'}27: {id: 28, name: 'GİRESUN'}28: {id: 29, name: 'GÜMÜŞHANE'}29: {id: 30, name: 'HAKKARİ'}30: {id: 31, name: 'HATAY'}31: {id: 32, name: 'ISPARTA'}32: {id: 33, name: 'İÇEL'}33: {id: 34, name: 'İSTANBUL'}34: {id: 35, name: 'İZMİR'}35: {id: 36, name: 'KARS'}36: {id: 37, name: 'KASTAMONU'}37: {id: 38, name: 'KAYSERİ'}38: {id: 39, name: 'KIRKLARELİ'}39: {id: 40, name: 'KIRŞEHİR'}40: {id: 41, name: 'KOCAELİ'}41: {id: 42, name: 'KONYA'}42: {id: 43, name: 'KÜTAHYA'}43: {id: 44, name: 'MALATYA'}44: {id: 45, name: 'MANİSA'}45: {id: 46, name: 'KAHRAMANMARAŞ'}46: {id: 47, name: 'MARDİN'}47: {id: 48, name: 'MUĞLA'}48: {id: 49, name: 'MUŞ'}49: {id: 50, name: 'NEVŞEHİR'}50: {id: 51, name: 'NİĞDE'}51: {id: 52, name: 'ORDU'}52: {id: 53, name: 'RİZE'}53: {id: 54, name: 'SAKARYA'}54: {id: 55, name: 'SAMSUN'}55: {id: 56, name: 'SİİRT'}56: {id: 57, name: 'SİNOP'}57: {id: 58, name: 'SİVAS'}58: {id: 59, name: 'TEKİRDAĞ'}59: {id: 60, name: 'TOKAT'}60: {id: 61, name: 'TRABZON'}61: {id: 62, name: 'TUNCELİ'}62: {id: 63, name: 'ŞANLIURFA'}63: {id: 64, name: 'UŞAK'}64: {id: 65, name: 'VAN'}65: {id: 66, name: 'YOZGAT'}66: {id: 67, name: 'ZONGULDAK'}67: {id: 68, name: 'AKSARAY'}68: {id: 69, name: 'BAYBURT'}69: {id: 70, name: 'KARAMAN'}70: {id: 71, name: 'KIRIKKALE'}71: {id: 72, name: 'BATMAN'}72: {id: 73, name: 'ŞIRNAK'}73: {id: 74, name: 'BARTIN'}74: {id: 75, name: 'ARDAHAN'}75: {id: 76, name: 'IĞDIR'}76: {id: 77, name: 'YALOVA'}77: {id: 78, name: 'KARABÜK'}78: {id: 79, name: 'KİLİS'}79: {id: 80, name: 'OSMANİYE'}80: {id: 81, name: 'DÜZCE'}length: 81[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Can you show the response returned for `getCities` as snippet? And show the implementation for `getCities` method in `LocationService`.

Comment: I have tested your code on stackblitz and it works. Perhaps the problem is from other pieces of code. Check the console for errors.

Comment: @YongShun Here is the implementation of LocationService:
`getCities(): Observable<City[]>{
    let url = this.baseUrl + "GetCities";

    return this.http.get<City[]>(url, {})
  }`

Comment: I added a sample for returned value. Also, there is no error in the console.

Comment: Is the booking component with `OnPush` detection strategy?

Comment: I don't know what OnPush detection strategy is, but I use reactive forms and listening FormControls in ngoninit function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. It is not related to angular, it is related to javascript. I am using a template which uses javascript and jquery - nice select. It just transforms my "select" element to div even before my constructor comes in, and it doesn't include my loop.

Thanks for the helps!